# I need to display results from time_ago_in_words as "days ago" only

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I pass Rails time_ago_in_words method a date which is greater than 1 month ago, it returns a string which reads something like "about N months old".

Is there anyway to have this method return the distance from the date paramater in days only i.e. 30 days ago, 50 days ago, 90 days ago etc...

Comment: What if the difference is less than 1 day?

Comment: if the distance is < 24 hours then displaying the minutes or hours is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Time
  def days_ago
    diff = Time.now - self
    return ago if diff < 86400
    "#{"day".pluralize(diff.to_i / 86400)} ago"
  end
end

class Date
  def days_ago
    to_time.days_ago
  end
end
```

Or as a helper:

```
def days_ago(date)
  diff = Time.now - date.to_time
  return date.ago if diff < 86400
  "#{"day".pluralize(diff.to_i / 86400)} ago"
end
```

Comment: The solution is correct, however I would suggest to create an helper instead of re-opening the Date and Time class.

Answer (score 4):

You could define your own helper on top of `time_ago_in_words`:

```
def days_ago_in_words(time)
  days = ((Time.now - time.to_time) / 86400.0).round
  if days > 1
    I18n.t :x_days, :count => days, :scope => :'datetime.distance_in_words'
  else
    time_ago_in_words(time)
  end
end
```

The I18n key and scope come from `distance_of_time_in_words` so you don't have to define your own.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The helper doesn't support it, here's the [definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L67).

However, your case is actually simpler than the helper logic. You can create a new helper that subtracts the old date from the current date, then divide the resulting number of seconds by (60 * 60 * 24) which is the number of seconds in a day and you get the result.